Application environment variable issue
I have changed my APP_ENV=local to APP_ENV=production, but when i am trying to get the value from \App::environment() it is showing the value "local", I have cleared the cache as well.
I changed my APP_ENV variable in the .env file to production, but Laravel is still returning local.

Please check your APP_ENV value in the correct environment file (config/app.php).
Sometimes, there might be multiple environment files for different environments (e.g., .env, .env.production, .env.local). Ensure you're modifying the right one.
Change accordingly and run the following commands:

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear

Please check and let me know
